# How to change the name of the table for an SQL INSERT EXTRACT in Dbeaver

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbeaver

I would like to extract result from a postgresSql query I made from a left join of two tables using DBEAVER:

```
select p.* from xxxxx as p 
left join xxxxxx as a on a.id=p.id
where p.id in ('id1','id2'...)
and p.e_d >= a._d::DATE
```

the issue is that the SQL INSERT extract result from these query includes all the query as the table to insert :

```
INSERT INTO "select p.* from xxxxx as p 
left join xxxxxx as a on a.id=p.id
where p.id in ('id1','id2'...)
and p.e_d >= a._d::DATE" (id,...) VALUES
(xxx,....)
```

how can I apply an alias for the query so that the INSERT query look like this ?

```
INSERT INTO "alias" (id,...) VALUES
(xxx,....)
```

Comment: You need "INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... " and not anything with VALUES. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dml-insert.html

Comment: When I ask for extraction in DBeaver with SQL INSERT format, that is the structure that DBeaver provides for the query (INSERT INTO "query" (column1,column2...) VALUE (value1,value2)...